# Grouping numeric distribution in R

Tags: r, grouping, aggregate

I have moved to `R` very recently and enjoying it ,so is there any way to group `X` values in `R`? I want to `group` by 10 and frequency would occur accordingly?

count(delivery_days)# `delivery_days` is the table `X` is delivery time taken for one product and freq I've gathered by the `count` code in `R`.

```
    x freq
1   3    1
2   4    1
3   5    1
4  10    1
5  12    2
6  25    3
7  32    1
8  45    1
9  65    1
10 78    1
```

Is there any packages need installing to get it or else please let me know .

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: What is `count` code?

Answer (score 1):

```
delivery_day=c(2,20,21,22,58,41)
myseq<-seq(from=0,to=max(delivery_day)+10,by=10)
delivery_day_cut<-cut(delivery_day,breaks=myseq)

  >[1] (0,10]  (10,20] (20,30] (20,30] (50,60] (40,50]
  >Levels: (0,10] (10,20] (20,30] (30,40] (40,50] (50,60]

table(delivery_day_cut)

  >delivery_day_cut
   (0,10] (10,20] (20,30] (30,40] (40,50] (50,60] 
       1       1       2       0       1       1
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question in not much clear,but as far as i have understood,you want to extract all X = 10 to be grouped ad one dataframe with all columns available.

Since delivery_days is your table name.

```
new_table <- delivery_days[delivery_days$X == 10,]
```